# Prevent any caching in the browser

Tags: http, express, cache-control

Which header(s) can I use to prevent any caching on the part of the browser?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

would it simply be:

```
res.setHeader('cache-control','no-cache');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cache-Control: no-store is sufficient.

See:
  https://www.mnot.net/blog/2017/03/16/browser-caching

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is the most comprehensive thing to do:

```
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
```

according to:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

but I guess one thing I don't understand - it seems like `must-revalidate` is redundant - I figure that `no-cache`/`no-store` already takes care of `must-revalidate` would otherwise do?